# UpdateOrCreate fails to update one column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

I`m coding Facebook Login with Laravel/Socialite.

I use UpdateOrCreate in the callback function, so if user does not exist, Laravel will create a new record, otherwise, will update some data on existing one.

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

        $key_token = $user->token;
        $key_fb = $user->getId();        
        $name = $user->getName();      
        $email = $user->getEmail(); 
        $url_photo = $user->getAvatar();   

        $user = User::updateOrCreate(
            [
                'email' => $email
            ],
            [   
                'name' => $name,
                'key_fb' => $key_fb,
                'url_photo' => $url_photo,
                'ḱey_token' => $key_token,
                'date_lastlogin' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
            ]
        );

        Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
        return redirect('home');
}
```

**But, be an Update or Create, the "key_token" is never inserted/updated. Mysql shows default value, Null. Other columns work fine.**

I checked the value of key_token and its filled in all contexts. 
Also, the User Model $fillable array contains "key_token" .

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'key_fb', 'url_photo', 'date_lastlogin', 'key_token',
    ];
```

I also have run the actual string (received token from FB) in the place of $key_token, but key_token continues to be filled with Null value.

(...)

```
 'url_photo' => $url_photo,
 'ḱey_token' => "IjasIJ937Jdsi823KJAndksu.......",
 'date_lastlogin' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
```

(...)

When echoing $user (from UpdateOrCreate return) , the value for key_token is Null

What to do in order to insert/update key_token?

Comment: try this and see if the key_token value is printed `dd($key_token)` before creating or inserting.

Comment: As I said above, it`s printed before the UpdateOrCreate(). If I change the $key_token variable with the actual string printed inside the UpdateOrCreate(), the db column continues with null value.

Comment: The array key  'ḱey_token' have a little accent over the k and in fillable array is written different

Comment: Can i see your migration of the User table?

Comment: @ErDiablo, you are right! Weird typo in key_token.

Comment: `key_token` has my name in it :D